# How to calculate the difference between time in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10

Anyone can tell how to **calculate the difference between time** here time is like IN , OUT, IN :-code what i am tried:-

```
@api.model
@api.depends('attendance_manage_lines.punch_time')
def _time_difference(self):
    ls=[] 
    for item in self.attendance_manage_lines:
        data = {}
        data[item.punch_time]=str(item.punch_type)
        ls.append(data)`
```

Now how to calculate :-[image]
here the difference between In and OUT comes in work duration AND OUT and IN comes in break duration.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


out = datetime.strptime(out, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
intime = datetime.strptime(intime, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
diff = out - intime
#here out and in are punch intime and out times.output would be exact difference in datetime object
```

Comment: What you mean, in your code? I can't see the calculation.